# Wait for an API request to finish so it can pass a variable for the next async iteration to use it

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've seen other questions related to this but I still can't solve this.

So basically what is happening right now is that it's executing the second request without waiting for the first request to finish and since the first request needs to change the apiurl of the second request when it finishes this wont work because it will keep using the same apiurl since the request didnt finish and changed the apiurl before the second one started

I want wait for the first request to finish so it can pass the new **apiurl** variable to the next request so it can fetch data from a different page, this is the code, hope its not too complicated:

```js
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const json2csv = require('json2csv');
const async = require('async');
const _ = require('underscore');
const RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
const flatten = require('flat');
const limiter = new RateLimiter(1, 500);
const credentials = require('dotenv').config();

let apikey = "someapikey";
let password = "somepassword";
let storeName = "somestorename";

let baseurl = 'https://' + apikey + ':' + password + '@' + storeName + '.myshopify.com';
let numOrders = 0;
let ordersList = [];
let countordersList = 0;
var nextLink;
var apiurl;



let getOrders = function(page, callback) {
    console.log(page);
    if (page == 1) {
        apiurl = baseurl + '/admin/orders.json?status=any&limit=250';
    }
    console.log(apiurl);

    request({
        url: apiurl,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            if (response.headers.link && response.headers.link.indexOf(`rel="next"`) > -1) {
                console.log(apiurl);

                try {
                    // Try to parse our the string we need
                    nextLink = response.headers.link;

                    // If there's a previous link, remove the first part of the string entirely
                    if (nextLink.indexOf(`rel="previous"`) > -1) {
                        nextLink = nextLink.substr(nextLink.indexOf(",") + 2, nextLink.length);
                    }

                    // Parse the remaining string for the actual link
                    nextLink = nextLink.substr(1, nextLink.indexOf(">") - 1);
                    // READY - CALL THE NEXT SET WITH NEXTLINK
                    apiurl = nextLink;
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(response.headers);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("ALL ORDERS EXPORTED");
                console.log(response.headers);
            }




            let newList = [];
            for (i = 0; i < body.orders.length; i++) {
                newList.push(flatten(body.orders[i]));
            }

            ordersList = ordersList.concat(newList);
            countordersList += ordersList.length;
            console.log('Orders received: ' + countordersList + ' / ' + numOrders);
            console.log();

            json2csv({
                    data: ordersList,
                    fields: ['order_number', 'email', 'financial_status', 'processed_at', 'fulfillment_status:', 'currency', 'total_price', 'browser_ip', 'gateway', 'billing_address.first_name', 'billing_address.last_name', 'billing_address.address1', 'billing_address.address2', 'billing_address.company', 'billing_address.city', 'billing_address.zip', 'billing_address.province', 'billing_address.province_code', 'billing_address.country', 'billing_address.country_code', 'billing_address.phone', 'shipping_address.first_name', 'shipping_address.last_name', 'shipping_address.address1', 'shipping_address.address2', 'shipping_address.company', 'shipping_address.city', 'shipping_address.zip', 'shipping_address.province_code', 'shipping_address.country_code', 'shipping_address.phone', 'line_items.0.name', 'line_items.0.quantity', 'line_items.0.price', 'line_items.0.sku', 'line_items.1.name', 'line_items.1.quantity', 'line_items.1.price', 'line_items.1.sku', 'line_items.2.name', 'line_items.2.quantity', 'line_items.2.price', 'line_items.2.sku', 'line_items.3.name', 'line_items.3.quantity', 'line_items.3.price', 'line_items.3.sku', 'line_items.4.name', 'line_items.4.quantity', 'line_items.4.price', 'line_items.4.sku']
                },
                function(err, csv) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    fs.appendFile(storeName + '.csv', csv, function(err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        ordersList = [];
                    });
                });

            callback();

        }


    })
}

request({
    url: baseurl + '/admin/orders/count.json?status=any',
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        numOrders = body.count;
    }
    console.log();
    if (numOrders > 700000) {
        numOrders = 700000;
    }
    console.log('Total: ' + body.count);
    console.log('Processing: ' + numOrders);
    console.log();
    let numPages = numOrders / 250;
    let r = _.range(1, numPages + 1);

    async.forEach(r, function(page, callback) {
        limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {
            getOrders(page, callback);
        })

    }, function(err) {
        // Called when all are finished
        console.log('Total: ' + ordersList.length);
        console.log();


    });


});
```

**What my script does:**

It gets a page with 250 orders from my Shopify store using the Shopify API and uses cursor-based pagination to request one page of orders at a time or at least that's what I want it to do, right now the requests are trying to get all pages at the same time since it doesnt wait for the first request to finish and it can't pass the new url variable apiurl to the next iteration, then it saves the info to a csv file but the relevant piece of code is the first half ot the getOrders function. I would really appreciate the help, I feel dumb for trying to solve it for the past 5 hours with almost no progress.

Comment: tried using async/await ?

Comment: @xMayank I tried but it gave an error because I didn't understand where to put the code it's really confusing for me, I was probably doing it wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `async.forEachSeries()`. It is the same as `async.forEach()` but runs only a single async operation at a time.

```
    async.forEachSeries(r, function(page, callback) {
       getOrders(page, callback);
    }, function(err) {
        // Called when all are finished
        console.log('Total: ' + ordersList.length);
        console.log();
    });
```

As you can see in the example below, there is no problem with the basic logic of the function `async.forEachSeries()`. You need to make sure that the `callback()` function in `getOrders()` is called properly.

```js
function getOrders(page, callback) {
  console.log('getOrders called with ' + page);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Call callback in getOrders');
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}

const r = [1, 2, 3, 4]

async.forEachSeries(r, function(page, callback) {
   getOrders(page, callback);
}, function(err) {
    // Called when all are finished
    console.log('Total: all orders finished');
    console.log();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/3.2.0/async.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but now it stops the whole loop when the request of the first iteration finishes not even running the request for the second iteration, do you know how to solve that? Thanks

Comment: @DavideGonçalves I updated the answer to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `async` module too. `async.waterfall` or `async.auto`

```
async.auto({
   first_req: function(callback) {
    request({
       url: apiurl,
       json: true
      }, function(error, response, body) {
       callback(null, body);
      }
     },
     second_req: ['first_req', function(results, callback) {
      // here you will get access to result of first request in results
      //process or request another link here and send data to callback
      callback(null, second_result);
     }],
   },
   function(err, results) {
    //[second_req] here you will get result of second request
    console.log('err = ', err);
    console.log('results = ', results);
   });
```

And instead of `forEach` go for `for...of` which will wait a process to complete.